# Decoding DTMF tones from recording

Tags: gratis, audio, data-analysis

I want to teach kids the decoding of alien messages. To get an idea of what aliens could send us, I use the [Arecibo message](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo-Botschaft#) as a first starting point. So I'm trying to decode that message. Wikipedia has an audio version [with DTMF](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3AArecibo_message_DTMF.ogg) for download. While it's unlikely that aliens will send properly formatted DTMF, let's still try to decode that first, as an exercise.

Of course I can use Audacity to have a look at the tones

[image: Audacity]

and there will be a noticeable enough distinction between 0 and 1. But decoding more than 1500 of there is still error prone, so I want some software to do that for me.

Which software could open a WAV or OGG file and decode DTMF?

Windows is preferred, but I also have a Raspberry Pi, so Linux might be an option, too.

The output would likely be a text file with just the DTMF numbers or characters, I guess. Other data formats are fine, too, as long as they are common.

Not suitable:

- [Polar Electric DTMF decoder](http://www.polar-electric.com/DTMF/Index.html) - not gratis and no longer for sale
- [DTMF Tone Decoder](http://www.audio-software.com/dtmf_tone_decoder.html) is not gratis and targets professionals, not hobbyists